What modelling technique to synthesize data based on sets of sequential, boolean samples?
I have ~100 datasets, each of which is an independent process describing the state of an independent machine. If the machine is in a first state, it is "True" and if it is in a second state, "False." In general, let's say 90% of timestamps are "True" and 10% "False". When False occurs, it is likely to be a sticky (i.e., to remain for at least a few timestamps).
Assuming I know nothing more about the physical process described, what techniques should I look into in order to synthesize additional datasets which have similar characteristics as these samples? For example, they should on a summary level have similar rates of True / False, but also have similar characteristics in terms of frequency of the event toggles.
A markov chain comes to mind, but I'm unsure if this is the best technique here. Any ideas?
